# TFS 2015 vNext build configuration + FIPS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to configure the vNext build on a Windows 2012 server, where the FIPS is enabled. I am getting exception as below:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

my question is:
IS FIPS disabling a prerequisites for the vNext build? Is there any work around other then not disabling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the build cannot work with FIPS enabled. There isn't any work around for this as I know. There is already a feature request for this on VSTS User Voice, you can check this link for details: [FIPS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/7751010-fips) and vote it.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i did vote. Can you help me understand if we can do the below and will it help? 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0bbb1862-4eb2-4f48-aba5-78a443a3d8ed/upgrade-to-tfs-2015fips-compliance?forum=tfsadmin

Comment: @Angshuman The thread is about upgrade to TFS 2015. However, the build still cannot work if the upgrade can be finished successfully. You can check this link for reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/389cf288-787b-4a4f-bdca-286f69eff7c6/is-team-foundation-server-2015-compatible-with-fips-compliance?forum=tfsadmin

Comment: thanks this helps. So basically while installing we can disable and then re-enable once the installation is over.